# Big CSV parsing

Tags: csv, vbscript

I'm having quite a hard time to figure out a robust and light algorithm for post-processing some big CSV files. Here's a minimal example of how they look like:

```
Time    a     b     c
0      2.9   1.6   4.1
0      3.6   1.1   0.5
0      3.4   0.2   1.7
1.2    0.1   4.2   1.9
1.201  2.3   3.1   4.8
9.99   0.2   0.8   1.2
10     3.1   3.3   2.3
10     3.6   3.5   3.0
10.01  1.1   4.5   3.9
10.01  2.2   3.0   2.3
17     4.3   2.3   3.8
20     1.0   3.2   3.0
30     4.1   3.0   4.9
40     3.8   3.3   1.6
```

I need to postprocess my CSV based on those rules:

1. only lines whose time is a multiple of 10 need to be considered
2. if multiple line have the same time tamp, take the average value of each column across the different rows

Here's the output I'd like to get:

```
Time    a     b     c
0      3.3   0.97  2.1
10     2.04  3.02  2.54
20     1.0   3.2   3.0
30     4.1   3.0   4.9
40     3.8   3.3   1.6
```

Now the constraint: my script needs to handle pretty big CSV (up to few hundreds MB) on a Windows machine without much memory available for this. Because of that, I'm not keen on storing all the CSV in a big array of dictionary, but I'd prefer to do this row by row.

Here's my first naive attempt. It's very poor and not properly working. (Small margin note: the average is not a true average but a kind of weird "running average". Bear with me here, I was trying to assess the workflow and don't really care for the numbers at this stage.)

```
filename = "test"
sampling_time = 10.0
tolerance = 1e-1

Dim FSO, input, output
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

'Create the objects
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set input = FSO.OpenTextFile(filename & ".csv", ForReading, False)
Set output = FSO.OpenTextFile(filename & "_output.csv", ForWriting, True)

'First line: write headers
s = input.ReadLine()
output.WriteLine s

'Second line: initialize sSplit_old
s = input.ReadLine()
sSplit = Split(s, ",")
sSplit_old = sSplit

'Keep reading...
Do Until input.AtEndOfStream
    'read new line and split it into its components
    'this is needed to read the first element of the line, i.e. the time
    s = input.ReadLine()
    sSplit = Split(s, ",")

    'If the remainder of time/sampling_time is below the tolerance then the
    'line has to be processed.
    'Here the "\" operator (i.e. the integer division: 5\2=2, while 5/2=2.5)
    'is used as the "Mod" operator return integer remainders.
    If CDbl(sSplit(0))-sampling_time*(CDbl(sSplit(0))\sampling_time) < tolerance Then
        'If the current time is close to the previous one (within a tolerance)...
        If Abs(CDbl(sSplit(0))-CDbl(sSplit_old(0))) < tolerance Then
            '... cycle through the arrays and store the average
            For i = 0 To UBound(sSplit)
                sSplit_old(i) = (CDbl(sSplit(i)) + CDbl(sSplit_old(i))) / 2.0
            Next
        Else
            '... otherwise just write the previous time and save the current
            'one to compare it to the next one
            s = Join(sSplit_old, ",")
            output.WriteLine s
            sSplit_old = sSplit
        End If
    End If
Loop

output.WriteLine s
input.Close
output.Close
```

Comment: It would be easier if you do this in a spreadsheet. Is VBA an option for you?

Comment: Nope. I need this as part of an automation script that needs to run on the machine generating the csv itself. It's part of an automation script that I'm writing to go from a huge datafile to a smaller ready to use dataset.

Comment: OK. What is the average number of rows that you expect the datafile to generate?

Comment: Few tens of thousands. And few hundreds columns.

Comment: Since you didn't mentioned a specific issue with your code (want a better algo), I suggest you move this to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How *exactly* is your code "not properly working"?

Comment: The code there is just a first attempt, but I feel that the algorithm is wrong. Basically I compare each time with the previous one and I accumulate them. Then, as soon as the time is different prom the previous one, I write the old line, where I have accumulated all the previous values. However, I don't know how to manage both the "multiples of ten" thing and the "accumulation" thing. My question was not supposed a code review, but an algorithm review, if this makes sense for you :)

Comment: Is the input file really in this format or is it *proper* CSV? Because if were proper CSV you could use the ADODB text file driver and do the entire task in as single SQL statement.

Comment: The input table in my question `Time,a,b,c` - newline - `0,2.9,1.6,4.1` ... Is this what you call _proper CSV_?

Comment: Yes. A single delimiter between fields, not what you show in your question. Lesson: Do not prettify your data samples. Show your data exactly as you have it, it may make a fundamental difference on how a task can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you paid (too much) for your Windows OS, you also paid for a SQL engine. So use it:

```
Option Explicit

Dim db : Set db = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim dd : dd = "E:\work\proj\soa\47155733\data"
Dim cs
If "AMD64" = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%") Then
   cs = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & dd & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
   WScript.Echo "64 Bit:", cs
Else
   cs = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" & dd & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
   WScript.Echo "32 Bit:", cs
End If
db.Open cs

Dim ss : ss = "SELECT * FROM [47155733.txt]"
WScript.Echo ss
WScript.Echo db.Execute(ss).GetString(2,,vbTab,vbCrlf,"*")

ss =   "SELECT t, avg(a), avg(b), avg(c) FROM [47155733.txt]" _
     & " WHERE t = Int(t) And 0.0 = t Mod 10 GROUP BY t"
WScript.Echo ss
WScript.Echo db.Execute(ss).GetString(2,,vbTab,vbCrlf,"*")

ss = "SELECT Round(1/3, 3)"
WScript.Echo ss
WScript.Echo db.Execute(ss).GetString(2,,vbTab,vbCrlf,"*")
```

output:

```
cscript 47155733.vbs
SELECT * FROM [47155733.txt]
0       2,9     1,6     4,1
0       3,6     1,1     0,5
0       3,4     0,2     1,7
1,2     0,1     4,2     1,9
1,201   2,3     3,1     4,8
9,99    0,2     0,8     1,2
10      3,1     3,3     2,3
10      3,6     3,5     3
10,01   1,1     4,5     3,9
10,01   2,2     3       2,3
17      4,3     2,3     3,8
20      1       3,2     3
30      4,1     3       4,9
40      3,8     3,3     1,6

SELECT t, avg(a), avg(b), avg(c) FROM [47155733.txt] WHERE t = Int(t) And 0.0 = t Mod 10 GROUP BY t
0       3,3     0,966666666666667       2,1
10      3,35    3,4     2,65
20      1       3,2     3
30      4,1     3       4,9
40      3,8     3,3     1,6

SELECT Round(1/3, 3)
0,333
```

Tested for 32 and 64 bit on Windows 10; German locale. I prefer to specify the file format in a schema.ini file:

```
[47155733.txt]
Format=Delimited(,)
ColNameHeader=True
DecimalSymbol=.
Col1=t Double
Col2=a Double
Col3=b Double
Col4=c Double
```

Background:

[Connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/), [odbc Connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-text-odbc-driver/), [Driver download](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/).

Comment: Exactly what I was about to propose. The one thing that should be added to the VBScript is `SetLocale "en-us"` (or whatever the OP prefers) to control how numbers are output in the string.

Comment: OP said that the expected file is few hundred MBs and there are hundreds of columns. ADODB might be painfully slow (and might not work at all given limited memory).